# How to cache JSON API data in PHP?

Tags: php, json, caching

I'm trying to understand how to cache data from an API (PokeAPI to be precise) to limit the amount of calls the application makes for the data.

For example, one of my functions gets "All Pokemon" from the API:

```
 function getAllPokemon() {
      $url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151';
      $response = Requests::get($url);
      $allPokemonData = json_decode($response->body, true);
      return $allPokemonData;
    }
```

I use the data in this function to build a menu of list items in my pokedex app. How can I cache the JSON results so that I don't have to call the api everytime the page reloads?

From my research I know the basics of what needs to be done, a cache needs to be created in a directory and the app needs to check to see if a cached file exists before making a call to the api, if does exist do not call, if it doesnt make a call to the api and cache for a specified amount of time - I cannot translate this into working code though? Can anyone show me and example or point me to any learning materials? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.php-cache.com/

Comment: You can use this: https://www.kevinleary.net/api-request-caching-json-php/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [redis](https://redis.io/) for cache values key > val. after first request you can save the fetched data with a key. the second and other fetches can receive which data cached in redis.

Here is tutorial for Redis and PHP https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-redis-in-php